# LISP Appropriate Way to Return Value From Function

Tags: functional-programming, common-lisp, sbcl

So I am working my way through Paul Graham's Common Lisp and one questions asks to create a union function that maintains the order of the elements in the lists being unionized. To that end I have written the following function:

```
(defun new-union (listA listB)
  (setq retset (list (car listA)))
  (loop for el in (append (cdr listA) listB)
    do (if (not(member el retset))
      (push el (cdr (last retset)))))
  (return-from new-union retset))
```

This returns the unique elements of each list while maintaining the order so if I create and run:

```
(setq listA '(a b c a))
(setq listB '(c d e))
(new-union listA listB)
```

The return is:

```
(A B C D E)
```

So the first things is I get a compiler warning: `"undefined variable: RETSET"` on this line: `(setq retset (list (car listA)))`. The other thing is that the above method seems to be a more "object-oriented" way of doing things rather than the LISP way with the `return-from` statement.

Is it possible to write this code in a more "lisp-appropriate" manner without the compiler error?

*Edit: using the answer from @Sylwester I have rewritten the function as follows and get no errors:

```
(defun new-union (listA listB)
 (let ((retset (list (car listA))))
   (loop for el in (append (cdr listA) listB)
         do (if (not (member el retset))
              (push el (cdr (last retset)))))
   retset))
```

Comment: Your function tries to push items to the end of a linked list. That's not a good use of singly-linked lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setq` is to update an existing binding and your variable `retset` is not created. How this is handled is not specified in the standard so you cannot depend on code that touches it. You make global variables with [`defparameter` and `defvar`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/m_defpar.htm) while you can make local variables with `&aux` in functions, `let` and `loop` can create variables with `with`. Thus:

```
(defun new-union (list-a list-b)
  (let ((retset (list (car list-a))))
    ...
    retset
    ))
```

Is the same as this using [&aux](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/03_dae.htm):

```
(defun new-union (list-a list-b &aux (retset (list (car list-a))))
  ...
  retset
  )
```

And also the same as [loop with clause](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/m_loop.htm):

```
(defun new-union (list-a list-b)
  (loop :with retset := (list (car list-a))
     ...
     :finally (return retset)))
```

About return values. In tail position the value evaluated is the returned value. eg.

```
(if (< 3 4)
    8
    10)
```

Here `8` is returned. That means `(return from new-union retset)` in your code, which is in tail position, could have been written just `retset`.

Now if you have code which is not in tail position and you wish to return early you can do what you did in tail position and it will work.

The one I use `(return retset)` returns from the nearest unnamed (`nil`) block while `return-from` returns from a named block. `loop` has the keyword `named` which allows you to choose the name of the block it produces.

Asking a lisper to implement such a trivial function you will get lots of answers. With the specifications and tests you had I would have done:

```
(defun new-union (&rest lists &aux (hash (make-hash-table :test 'equal)))
  (loop :for list :in lists
        :nconc (loop :for element :in list 
                     :if (gethash element hash t)
                         :collect element
                         :do (setf (gethash element hash) nil))))
```

Comment: While I found your final implementation too far removed from my solution, I did change the `setq` line to  a `let`. You can see my fixed implementation in my edit.

Comment: `Return` returns from a block named `nil`, not from any block.

Comment: @Svante updated. Still returns from the nearsest obe, bur so does `return-from`

Comment: To be precise, `(return …)` does the same as `(return-from nil …)`.  Every block has a name (it is not optional).  `Loop` uses a default name of `nil`.

Comment: @Svante Yeah, but it might be side effects if you name your blocks `nil`. `(loop :named nil :for lst :in lsts :do (loop :for e :in lsts :when (eq needle e) :do (return-from nil t))`

Answer (score 3):

A slightly better list-based version:

- union for more than two lists
- does not use LAST
- still uses MEMBER
- does not use APPEND
- DOLIST returns the value RETSET

Code

```
(defun new-union (&rest lists
                  &aux (retset (list (caar lists)))
                       (rretset retset))
  (dolist (list lists retset)
    (dolist (el list)
      (unless (member el retset)
        (setf (cdr rretset) (list el)
              rretset (cdr rretset))))))
```